# Paypal sandbox account could not be created

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox

When I try to create a business sandbox account it first has a status of processing but then always results in an error status code. It says the sandbox account could not be created, please delete it and create another one.

I saw that the paypal forms have some validation issues so I have already tried the following:

- Password more than 8 characters containing uppercase,lowercase,numbers and symbol characters.
- Positive balance < $1000
- Valid fictional email address that is not the same as my address.
- Tried different countries including the US.
- Filled in the optional fields of first name and last name

But still the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using a different **browser**. So I guess this was **cache** related in some way. I entered the following data:

- Country: United States
- Didn't fill in optional fields
- Bank verified
- Visa
- $100 in account

I used **Microsoft Edge** instead of *Chrome*.